# Error logging into instagram with python

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, mechanize

I am trying to log into my instagram via a python script using argparse. It seems to connect but it prints out "*This page could not be loaded. If you have cookies disabled in your browser, oryou are browsing in Private Mode, please try enabling cookies or turning off Private Mode, and then retrying your action.*"
Here's my code:

```
import argparse
import mechanicalsoup
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Login to Instagram.')
parser.add_argument("username")
parser.add_argument("password")
args = parser.parse_args()

browser = mechanicalsoup.Browser()

login_page = browser.get("https://instagram.com/accounts/login/?force_classic_login=&next=/oauth/authorize/?client_id=9d836570317f4c18bca0db6d2ac38e29%26redirect_uri=http://websta.me/%26response_type=code%26scope=comments%2Brelationships%2Blikes")

# we grab the login form
login_form = login_page.soup.select(".dialog-main")[0].select("#login-form")[0]

# specify username and password
login_form.select("#id_username")[0]['value'] = args.username
login_form.select("#id_password")[0]['value'] = args.password

#submit
page2 = browser.submit(login_form, login_page.url)
#verify login
p = page2.soup.p.string
print(p)
print(args.password)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a [library](https://github.com/Instagram/python-instagram) to access [instagram](https://www.instagram.com) from [python](https://www.python.org). To login, you need the following code:

```
from instagram.client import InstagramAPI

access_token = "YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN" # get this from instagram
client_secret = "YOUR_CLIENT_SECRET" # this, too, from instagram
api = InstagramAPI(access_token=access_token, client_secret=client_secret)
recent_media, next_ = api.user_recent_media(user_id="userid", count=10)
for media in recent_media:
    print media.caption.text
```

In other words, don't reinvent the wheel.

Answer (score 0):

See this answer you need to also include the client secret now to login to the API using that library.

[Debugging Python Instagram API client - 'NoneType' has no len()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30442663/debugging-python-instagram-api-client-nonetype-has-no-len)