# Error logging into Instagram in iOS app using UIWebView

Tags: ios, iphone, uiwebview, instagram, instagram-api

I'm following [Instagram authentication](https://www.instagram.com/developer/authentication/) [recommended] steps using UIWebView on an iOS app. 
After entering credentials, hitting login loads a page with following error.

> This page could not be loaded. If you have cookies disabled in your
>   browser, or you are browsing in private mode, please try enabling
>   cookies or turning off private mode, and then retrying your action.

And, this only happens on first run through the steps of authentication; on the next attempt, everything works smooth as silk. I get the code suffixed to redirect url and I request access token using it.

Screenshot:

[image]

There's already another question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30389316/error-logging-into-instagram-with-python) and it doesn't help.

**EDIT:**
It seems like Cookies issue. Though, I haven't been able to fix it yet.

Comment: maybe do a force redirection when you see this error ?

Comment: Could you be able to solve this?

Comment: No, not completely. I observed that webView's shouldStartLoadWithRequest experiencing bit of delay reduces frequency of this bugs occurrence.

Comment: did you manager to solve the problem ?

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem when I was deleting cookies to make sure the log in screen appeared and not just using the currently logged in user. Try (swift):

```
let storage = HTTPCookieStorage.shared
storage.cookieAcceptPolicy = .always
```

Comment: I tried it before posting the question. Unfortunately, it didn't solve my problem.

Answer (score 1):

I managed to solve this problem about an hour ago.

First, DON'T use UIWebView or WebView; use a [WKWebView](https://developer.apple.com/reference/webkit/wkwebview) instead.

You see, you need to implement the method

```
- (void)webView:(WKWebView *)webView didFailProvisionalNavigation:(null_unspecified WKNavigation *)navigation withError:(NSError *)error
```

when instagram's login page forwards you to your redirect_url , it FAILS to navigate. Probably because we're not doing the server-side auth, but only the client-side auth, and the redirect_url is not a valid url.
We're expecting the page to REDIRECT to an invalid url, but when that happens, the WKWebView doesn't call the method

```
- (void)webView:(WKWebView *)webView didCommitNavigation:(WKNavigation *)navigation
```

or the method

```
- (void)webView:(WKWebView *)webView didFinishNavigation:(WKNavigation *)navigation
```

So. What you need to do is focus on that first method, check the `error` variable, and extract `error.userInfo`.

In my case, this is how I solved the problem:

```
- (void)webView:(WKWebView *)webView didFailProvisionalNavigation:(null_unspecified WKNavigation *)navigation withError:(NSError *)error
{
   
    NSURL *err = [error.userInfo objectForKey:@"NSErrorFailingURLKey"];

    if([err.absoluteString hasPrefix:INSTA_REDIRECT_URL]){
        NSString *token = [[err.absoluteString componentsSeparatedByString:@"#access_token="] objectAtIndex:1];
        
     
        [Utils saveToken:token];
        [self.webView setHidden:YES];
        //open next view controller
    }else{
        //TODO: No internet? something else went wrong..
        
        NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
    }
    
}
```

Hope it helps.
Best of luck! ;)

Comment: Just tried this but `didFailProvisionalNavigation` is never called.