# Error Logging into Instagram ( Disabled Cookies ) - React Native WebView

Tags: react-native, cookies, webview, oauth, instagram

My app uses Instagram OAuth, it opens the Instagram login page from this url:

> "https://www.instagram.com/oauth/authorize/client_id=${clientId}&redirect_uri=${redirectUrl}&response_type=${responseType}&scope=${scopes.join('+')}"

Here the user can enter their username and password and press the login button. However the first time they enter Instagram throws off an error. The second time the link is opened, it has the users data and navigates the user to the app's home screen.

**Error**

> This page could not be loaded. If you have cookies disabled in your browser, or you are browsing in private mode, please try enabling cookies or turning off private mode, and then retrying your action.

[image: Instagram Error - Cookies are Disabled]

Here is the webView render function;

```
render() {
    const { uri } = this.state;

    if(this.state.loading){
        return <SpinnerComponent size={'small'}/>;
    }

    return (
        <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
            <WebView 
                startInLoadingState
                onNavigationStateChange={this.onNavigationStateChange.bind(this)}
                source={{ uri }}
                style={{flex: 1}}
            />
        </View>
    );
}
```

**Note**

I am using [react-native-cookie](https://github.com/shimohq/react-native-cookie) package, to delete cookies belonging to Instagram when the user logs out of the app. This is most probably the issue. However I cannot delete this package from my code base because it is a necessary part of logging out procedure. To counter this I have implemented the below code in the WebView's "componentDidMount" LifeCycle Method, to get cookies from the site. But it does not help my case.

> Cookie.get(`https://www.instagram.com`);

Here is a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37660981/error-logging-into-instagram-in-ios-app-using-uiwebview) on stackoverflow experiencing the exact same problem. However the solution given is in Obj-C or Swift, both of which I have no knowledge of. I haven't been able to find a solution for React Native.

Comment: Did you manage to solve this? I'm having the same issue.

Comment: No I haven't been able to remove this error ... I think the only possible solution is to write native code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On webapp authentication... the problem is related to instagram platform. I found that the problem arise only if your browser don't have the instagram cookie "ig_cb" set. 
This is set when you accept cookie policy on instagram.com.
The workaround is to go on instagram and accept cookie policy then go back to your social auth and proceed.

Being a block on instagram login process... I guess there's no definitive solution other than wait for instagram bug fix.