# Instagram login error: "This page could not be loaded. If you have cookies disabled in your browser..."

Tags: ios, instagram, instagram-api

I have an Instagram social login implemented and it was working as expected until few days ago. Now when you try to log in, and just after the user inputs its username and password, the web view shows an error related to disabled cookies. I have not changed anything on my side... It is happening in both iOS and Android platform.

I've tried to log in using VPN to a non Europe country and the login works as expected... Have any of you encountered this issue?

This is the error I get:

> Error
>
> This page could not be loaded. If you have cookies disabled in your browser, or you are browsing in Private Mode, please try enabling cookies or turning off Private Mode, and then retrying your action.

[image: This page could not be loaded.]

Comment: Did you look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37660981/error-logging-into-instagram-in-ios-app-using-uiwebview ??

Comment: Yes, and it does not work.

Comment: Similar q -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50530404/bug-with-instagram-api-login-this-page-could-not-be-loaded . It seems that this is a CDPR issue.

Comment: I have tried the following answers and none worked - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37660981/error-logging-into-instagram-in-ios-app-using-uiwebview?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa

Comment: @Darkwonder How do you reproduce it in the first place? Do you have to use VPN and mock as a user in Europe?

Comment: @user1017674 I live in EU. You can follow the bug fix process here:  https://developers.facebook.com/support/bugs/406930029718049/ . NOTE: I use the old instagram API for client side auth (macOS). I also tried the new API for client side auth. https://www.instagram.com/developer/authentication/ . There I am presented with other errors which when solved lead me to the same cookie message error. There seems no way on the client side to solve this issue which is confirmed by the Facebook Team post from the link.

Comment: Thanks @user1017674 for the heads up

Answer (score 1):

Facebook have now resolved the issue as per the issued bug report previously mentioned by @user1017674
https://developers.facebook.com/support/bugs/406930029718049/

They didn't provide details on what caused the bug, but now it seems like you will be redirected to the new design of the Instagram login form rather than the classic one.

Answer (score 0):

You need to go to the Instagram home page first and click "allow cookies". After that open the link in the password reset email again.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Errors snapshot:]

What helped in my case is going on the homepage, site settings, and allowing "Unsafe content". Reload after changing, and repeating the normal procedure with the last password you entered that you want to be now your actual PWD - and worked.