# Bug with Instagram API Login - This page could not be loaded

Tags: ios, authentication, instagram, instagram-api

Since few days I have problems with the API instagram. Instagram sending this error page after the user has entered this login information.

"This page could not be loaded. If you have cookies disabled in your browser, or you are browsing in private mode"

Do you know why ? How to do ? Need help

[image]

Comment: found something?

Comment: I have tried the following answers and none worked : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37660981/error-logging-into-instagram-in-ios-app-using-uiwebview?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa

Answer (score 3):

On webapp authentication... the problem is related to instagram platform. I found that the problem arise only if your browser don't have the instagram cookie "ig_cb" set. This is set when you accept cookie policy on instagram.com. The workaround is to go on instagram and accept cookie policy then go back to your social auth and proceed.

This happens for both mobile and desktop users (browser).

Being a block on instagram login process... I guess there's no definitive solution other than wait for instagram bug fix.

Comment: I believe the answer is correct. Read the Facebook Team response on this issue : https://developers.facebook.com/support/bugs/406930029718049/

Answer (score 2):

I hate to be the bearer of bad news, but we also had this problem, which flagged on the Facebook Dev page: https://developers.facebook.com/support/bugs/406930029718049/

They have looked into the problem, as a number of us have had this exact issue too. It is only affecting EU user, as our US users are logging in and signing up without problems, and it seems that Facebook are refusing to look into it - their Instagram Platform API forum has already stopped accepting issues.

In terms of what we have learnt since last week, we think:

- It is likely GDPR related

  - Not all apps have been affected, Bumble does not have this problem but Tinder does
  - It is happening with both the old Platform API and Graph API, according to a developer who has already migrated to Graph.
  - No one seems to know anything!

**UPDATE:**

So it seem's it is in fact a cookie issue on mobile. When a user goes to sign in on mobile view, the 'accept cookie' message that typically appears on web doesn't appear. However, when the error screen pops up, if you click 'Log in' in the top right, it will redirect you to the web view, which lets you accept the new terms and conditions. Then, once you direct back to mobile the cookie seems to have been saved and you can now login. This has worked for us on iOS so far, but not Android, and we still haven't come up with a work-around yet.

Comment: How do you reproduce this issue? I tried using VPN to mock a europe user but I cannot reproduce the issue. We are getting reports of it happening but we can't reproduce it!

Comment: We are based in the London, UK, so we are in the affected area already. However, when we VPN to mock the US it is fine. Likewise, we had a London-based user sign-up whilst in the US and they were fine.

Comment: Are you guys using client sign up only? Or Server-side flow?

Comment: client-side, have a look at the update above and see if it helps you

Answer (score 1):

This bug [has now been fixed](https://developers.facebook.com/support/bugs/406930029718049/).

> Thank you all for your comments, individual input, and patience while we worked to address this issue for everyone.
>
> I am happy to report that this particular issue with Instagram login should now be resolved, but if you are still seeing any issues related to this fix, please let us know on this report only.